# How exactly does buffer flushing work (Difference between std::endl and \n)?

Tags: c++

So, I just got into 'C++' dev, and I am wondering how, exactly std::endl and \n differ. I looked it up, and I think endl flushes the buffer, which, I believe, means its no longer being temporarily stored in memory, and is now being printed out into a text file or a terminal. My question, though, is whether you can use \n for console applications too, which is printing onto a terminal, and it outputs the same. Is my interpretation of the buffer and flushing wrong? If so, what exactly does these mean?

EDIT: The question is mainly about how \n can behave the same way in the terminal if things are only outputted onto the terminal if they've been flushed.

Answer (score 2):

Using `std::endl` is not the *only* thing that flushes `cout`.

Reading from `cin` will also cause the `cout` buffer to be flushed, so that prompts can be visible on the console. By default the streams are ["tied"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/tie) to each other.

Comment: You may also want to note that `std::flush` also flushes the buffer (which is what `std::endl` does internally after outputting the `\n`.